Minor version not working with Asp.Versioning in .Net 8.0
Using .Net 8.0
We were using deprecated Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning. Now we are migrating and removing it and using below 2 packages:
PackageReference Include="Asp.Versioning.Mvc" Version="8.1.0"   
PackageReference Include="Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer" Version="8.1.0" />

I am unable to use minor version (.0) when code is deployed; though it is working fine in debug mode.
That means:

http://localhost:7001/api/v1/NameController/ActionMethod is working
http://localhost:7001/api/v1.0/NameController/ActionMethod is not working

It is mandatory for us to support both 1 and 1.0 as it is being used many clients and projects now irrespectively which cannot be changed.
Expecting both these urls to work
https://localhost:7001/api/v1/NameController/ActionMethod
https://localhost:7001/api/v1.0/NameController/ActionMethod

Getting

404 - Method not found for URL - https://localhost:7001/api/v1.0/NameController/ActionMethod

What am I doing wrong here?
Startup.cs
services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer(); 
services.AddApiVersioning(config => {     
config.ReportApiVersions = true;     
config.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(        
new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader()); }).AddMvc() 
.AddApiExplorer(options => {     
options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";     
options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true; }); 

Controller
[ApiVersion("1.0")] 
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v1")]
[ApiController]
public class NameController 
{ 
       [MapToApiVersion("1.0")] 
       [HttpPost("ActionMethod")] 
       public ActionMethod(parameters) 
       { 
         
       } 
}


Your codes worked well in my side and I'm able to visit https://localhost:7001/api/v1.0/ or https://localhost:7001/api/v2.0/. I put all the 3 post method in the same Controller with different MapToApiVersion attribute for test. Could you please provide a minimal a sample for reproducing the issue?

Can you please try running this in deployed service like - https://example.com/api/v2.0 and https://example.com/api/v2

Yeah I test it and it worked well too. I published the app to Azure web app, worked all the same as in localhost.

Thanks for testing it. I think there is some issue with property SubstituteApiVersionInUrl. When I set it to false, it works locally as well in deployed service. Also, there is contradictory points mentioned about this property.

There are some clashing points mentioned about this property in https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/370 and https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Explorer-Options. Anyway, I am posting these links here so that it can be useful for any user facing such issue in future. If anyone can suggest/explain why the asked question is working locally but not working when deployed, please let me know. Thanks!

In my side, SubstituteApiVersionInUrl was set to true and it worked as well. Anyway, you found  a workaround to solve your issue which is good. Since your issue only occurred after deployment, I'm afraid it's due to the web server.

Hmm, if possible can you please provide any suggestions if any specific things I can check related to sever.

sorry I don't have any ideas about it..

There are a couple of things going on. A functional repro would be useful. Let's tackle them one issue at a time.
Issue 1
OpenAPI and Swagger UI do not have anything to do with this issue directly. SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true simply substitutes {version} in your route template instead of it being a parameter.
The format used for the substituted API version is based on SubstitutionFormat, which has a default value of "VVV". This will include the major version and optional minor version if provided and non-zero. You can clear the format with "" or set it to "VV" to explicitly require major and minor version. You will then see the version appear as v1.0 instead of v1.
Remember that the GroupNameFormat is about how you want the API version formatted for the purposes of the ApiDescription.GroupName. v is not formally part of the API version, but it is a literal token in the route template. Many, but not all, people want the v prefix in the group name, which can be denoted by "'v'VVV".
Issue 2
The API Explorer extensions for API Versioning automatically group APIs according their (formatted) API version.
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v1")]

is therefore redundant and unnecessary. Furthermore, since you have elected to interleave API versions, this will cause problems for 2.0 as it will still be grouped by "v1". The API Explorer extensions would have otherwise automatically grouped 1.0 as "v1" and 2.0 as "v2"
I recommend removing this attribute.
Issue 3
You aren't combining different IApiVersionReader instances so:
ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader());

is unnecessary. This will result in a level of indirection that isn't needed. In fairness, the implementation could check for length 1 as an optimization and return the one reader, but it doesn't. More than anything, it is confusing to a reader maintaining the code.
Issue 4
The controller example provided isn't runnable, but with a few minor tweaks, I came up with this working implementation:
[ApiVersion( "1.0" )]
[ApiVersion( "2.0" )]
[Route( "api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]" )]
[ApiController]
public class NameController : ControllerBase
{
    [MapToApiVersion( "1.0" )]
    [HttpPost( nameof(ActionMethod) )]
    public IActionResult ActionMethod() => Ok();
}

It works and runs exactly as expected.

POST api/v1/Name/ActionMethod HTTP/2
POST api/v1.0/Name/ActionMethod HTTP/2

Both work.

A Debug versus Release build makes no difference here unless there is something particular in your codebase that hasn't been shared. Switching SubstitutionFormat = "VVV" will explicitly force URLs to be substituted with "v1.0" so you can test that path with the Swagger UI.
If that isn't working, my best theory is that there may URL rewriting or a reverse proxy (ex: YARP) in the middle and that hasn't been shared. Since you are versioning by URL segment, these middlewares need to account for matching "v1" and "v1.0". The regular expression might look like [vV]\d(\.\d+)?. This is just one of the many issues with versioning by URL segment (aside from not being RESTful).
